# Elasticsearch could not search on string field

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest, elasticsearch.net

I am trying to use NEST to create search query dynamically based on user's input.
I want to add multiple filter in Filter with Term but string field searching is not possible and I cannot find any solution.

Code for example is that, this code try to search on string field an it is not working

```
var response = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<CustomerAddressInfo>(p => p
            .Query(q => q
                .Bool(b => b
                    .Filter(f => f.Term(t => t.Field(p => p.AccountAddressId).Value(type.AccountAddressId)))
                )
            )
        );
```

And the other search simple is with integer field and it is working with success

```
var response = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<CustomerAddressInfo>(p => p
            .Query(q => q
                .Bool(b => b
                    .Filter(f => f.Term(t => t.Field(p => p.CreateUnitId).Value(type.CreateUnitId)))
                )
            )
        );
```

But; if I search data on string field with Match keyword, again it is successfull on search

```
var response = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<CustomerAddressInfo>(p => p
            .Query(q => q
                .Match(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.AccountAddressId)
                    .Query(type.AccountAddressId)
                )
            )
        );
```

And the question is, how can I give multiple search criteria with Match query method or how can I seach on string field by Term query method on elastic

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with NEST, but to search on multiple fields using match query or term query, you can refer following example :

Bool query is used to combine one or more clauses, to know more refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Avoid using the [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) for text fields.

> By default, Elasticsearch changes the values of text fields as part of
> analysis. This can make finding exact matches for text field values
> difficult.
>
> To search text field values, use the match query instead.

**Index Mapping**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "cost": {
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index data:**

```
{
    "name":"apple",
    "cost":"40"
}
{
    "name":"apple",
    "cost":"55"
}
```

**Search Query: Multiple Search criteria with match**

```
   {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "name": "apple" }},
        { "match": { "cost": 40 }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search on-field by term query**

```
  {
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" :[
         {"term" : { "name" : "apple" }},
         {"term":  { "cost":40 }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "my-index",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "3",
    "_score": 1.1823215,
    "_source": {
      "name": "apple",
      "cost": "40"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need the solution for search with NEST on .netcore

Answer (score 0):

Hey i do not get the whole requirements of yours. But if you want to add multiple condition on filter then you can do like below.

```
QueryContainer qSs = null;
foreach(var query in queries) // let say queries is list of yours search item
{
  qSs &= new TermQuery { Field = "your_field_name", Value = query  };
}

 var searchResults = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<CustomerAddressInfo>(s => s
                .Query(q => q
                     .Bool(b => b.Filter(qSs)  )
                     )
                );
```